# How can I make multiple animations for one object?

Tags: animation, unity

Before anything else is said, I know this has already been asked, but I wasn't able to get a straight answer from any previous posts. What I am trying to do is create multiple animations for one object (A simple minecraft-type man).

I was able to make a basic animation by creating a new action for each body part to move (Legs/Arms). This worked great, but I realized that it was highly inefficient, and I couldn't group the actions together in any way. I did some tutorials, and found out I could assign multiple objects to one action. This was not the solution, because all the objects move the exact same way (Legs and Arms would all move together)

What I am trying to accomplish is to create one object, and have several organized animations for it, this way I can place the object into Unity and implement them into a game.

Comment: If its the exact same animation for both the arms and legs, I believe you could copy/paste the animation sequence

Comment: I think this might be what you're looking for. http://darkscarab.com/view/59

Comment: can we get a blend file from you?